# extract software serials from a computer

Tags: windows

Is there a free software for windows that I can use to extract software serial keys?
I have just bought my laptop and I want to use the serial on my desktop because I'll be using this more now.

Answer (score 1):

[Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) let's you **recover** license keys of installed software.

Note: if you bought the licenses through an OEM (pre-installed on the laptop), you will most likely violate their terms of service!

Answer (score 1):

Try [keyfinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) by Magic Jelly Beans.
The freeware version can find the serial of Windows / Office and many other products.